# using mongoose.model.update in array.map method but not working?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want update the value of a key in my database but it is not working. Kindly look into my code below.

```
if (req.body.Body != 'Hi') {
    Chat.find({ isBot: true }).sort({ sentTime: -1 }).limit(1).exec(function (err, message) {
      message.map(each => {
        console.log(each.queryType) 
        if (each.queryType === 'ask_email') {  //true
          console.log(req.body.Body); //get required data
          console.log(each._id); also getting id as plain text
          Chat.update({ _id: `ObjectId("${each._id}")` }, { $set: { MessageReceieved: req.body.Body } });

        }
        else if (message.queryType === 'ask_email' && each.MessageReceieved != null) {
          sendMessage('Kindly provide password', from, 'ask_password')
        }
        else if (each.queryType === 'ask_password' && each.MessageReceieved === null) {
          Chat.update({ _id: each._id }, { $set: { MessageReceieved: req.body.Body } });

        }

      })


    });
  }
```

I have also tried by changing to updateone but no resolution. Kindly suggest

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
Chat.findByIdAndUpdate({
                _id: each._id
            }, {
                $set: {
                    MessageReceieved: req.body.Body
                }
            }).then(chat => {
                // for respond
           }).catch(error => {
                // for debugin error
            })
```

Comment: Thanks for the help finally this worked. Thank you very much. One more question. Is using then catch is compulsory to get this work

Comment: findbyidandupdate return promise to handle you need to use then and catch method or inside async method and then put await  infront  findbyidandupdate

Answer (score 0):

try like the following:

```
Chat.findByIdAndUpdate(each._id, { MessageReceieved: req.body.Body  })
```

Comment: I tried this just not but not working. Kindly share other solution. I just want the update to work. Also note that I am using it under  Array.map().

Comment: do you want to use async loop???after this query does data updated in DB?

Comment: Kindly help as I am new to Nodejs and Mongoose. But it is not a big issue for experienced developers. No I dont want to use async loop. I just want the update to work